# How to call svelte:component current component method?

Tags: svelte

I have this basic app, with some components that have a public `load` method. On some actions, I'd like to call that method on the current svelte:component, but I have no idea how to get a reference to the component instance. How can one do that?

```
    <script>
        import router from 'page'
        import Wines from './pages/Wines.svelte'
        import Entry from './pages/Entry.svelte'
        import TitleBar from './components/TitleBar.svelte'

        let page,
            params

        router('/', () => page = Wines)
        router('/wines', () => page = Wines)
        router('/entry/:id?', (ctx, next) => {
            params = ctx.params
            next()
        }, () => page = Entry)

        async function forceSync(){
            // how to call current component instance?
        }

    </script>

    <main>
        <TitleBar on:sync-request={forceSync}></TitleBar>
        <svelte:component this={page} params={params}/>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `bind:this` to get a reference to the current component and assign it to a variable. This also works for components rendered with `<svelte:component>` so you would organize you code similar to:

```html
<script>
  import Child from './Child.svelte'

  let cmp

  const func = () => {
    // use cmp here: cmp.load()
  }
</script>

<svelte:component this="{Child}" bind:this="{cmp}" />
```

Comment: We can get a component reference but that does not allow us to use functions, that are defined on the component. svelte only provides a `$set` to update props but no `$get` to read the state (and probably execute an exported arrow function)

Comment: At least, if you do export a function on the component

Comment: Ahh, I failed first for whatever reason with my REPL. Now I got it. Yay!! Thanks!! https://svelte.dev/repl/8ba4270a9e334f35a591cdbfbac70e8e?version=3.22.3

Comment: right, I had tried to replace this={child} with bind:this but the compiler complained. I didn't think we could use both, as it seems to me that `this` is bound twice.

Comment: How can I pass $event to the child so as to prevent default?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I'm pretty sure that we can't access functions on the component scripts. I didn't find any hint on the API and couldn't find any of the methods via devTools.</strike>

**See the edit below**

But we can send functions via custom events and you could solve your requirement like this:

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import A from './A.svelte'
    const syncMethods = []

    function sync() {
        syncMethods.forEach(f => f());
    }

    function storeSyncHandler(event) {
        syncMethods.push(event.detail);
    }
</script>

<button on:click={sync}>Sync Components</button>
<A on:mounted={storeSyncHandler}/>
```

A.svelte

```
<script>
    import { createEventDispatcher, onMount} from 'svelte';
    const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

    let synced = ''

    function sync() {
        synced = '[SYNCED]';
    }

    onMount(() => {
        dispatch('mounted', sync)
    })
</script>

<div>Syncable Component {synced}</div>
```

The child component sends a 'mounted' event with it's 'sync' method. The parent stores that and can call it when ever needed. Hope it helps or gives some ideas.

Here's the REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/6bc923a8326643cca79a6a2f8ee0ffe0?version=3.22.3

Edit:

It works like a charm when we export the function on the other component.

Here's the working REPL to call methods on mounted components:

https://svelte.dev/repl/8ba4270a9e334f35a591cdbfbac70e8e?version=3.22.3